# Using PHP show 404 page

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

can anyone help me out with how to show 404 page using PHP. like

if(//some false condition):
//show 404 page, that normally comes up when we enter incorrect URL
endif;

Also i want the url in the address bar to be the incorrect one and not redirect me to 404 page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Display a 404 page without redirecting to the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137625/php-display-a-404-page-without-redirecting-to-the-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) use **.htaccess** file

2) put a line of code into it :  **ErrorDocument 404 /404.php**

3) content of 404.php is something like :

Sorry, the page you requested cannot be found.
Please check and retype the URL.

- relax , **the url would not change**, still the one that visitor typed