# Code Igniter: how not to show incomplete pages in case of error

Tags: php, codeigniter

1) I have a view (a neseted one) that triggers a notice-level error

2) I have set up a custom error handler, which is called. Code goes below

3) I want visitor seeing **only the "error happened" string** in his browser, instead, he sees the half-baked page with this error message appended

4) messing with php's native ob_end_clean only made me clear the contents of the deepest view involved, yet the higher-level views are still half-shown

5) the contents of final_output var of CI_Ouput class is empty string at the moment of error. That's strange is CI is said to pre-buffer everything befoew outputting to the client.

essentially, what I need seems to be discarding any content having been collected so far and replacing it with error message only.

how can I do it?

the code of the handler:

```
function _error_handler($errno, $errstr) {
    echo "error happened";
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Try Catch system?

```
Try{
//Do something
} catch(Exception $e){
echo "Error has occured!";
}
```

Comment: should be `Exception $e`

Comment: okay, I've tried it. I wrapped in try the entire controller code and threw exception from within the nested view. The result: half baked page with "error has occured" in the end.

Comment: what exactly makes the CI pre-buffer everything and output it in the very end of the execution (so that if I die before it doesn't get outputted)? Must be a really basic thing.

Comment: Take a quick look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137625/php-display-a-404-error-without-redirecting-to-another-page

Comment: thanks, have checked that one too. There they suggest redirect with a header. Doesn't work in my case as some content seems to have already been sent to the browser=>cant' send any headers. Redirect is not an option either. With header; die; approach is still see the half-ready page

Comment: If that's the case you can try to wait with displaying content to the browser untill the very end of your code. that way when you get an error you can redirect using the header function and if there is no error all your content will be displayed correctly

Comment: cool. how? That's exactly what I need. So if I die before the happy end, I show only the error message and the rest of (possibly) generated stuff goes to trash. My problem is I don't know how to do it in CI. More specifically, CI seems to have to do that by default without any effort from me, but it doesn't

Comment: Move all echos,print_r,etc.. to the bottom of your code. Or are you doing other stuff that generates content?

Comment: I'm rendering view that include plain HTML as well as some <?php echo "qqq" ?> code. One of the view in its php insertion has an error which causing this issue. So those prints are parts of view rendering and i don't know how to move them below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84767/discussion-between-homeless-person-and-user1312695).

Comment: I think this might be able to help you : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in the discussion this had to be related to php's native output buffering wich we can control with ob_* family of functions. Buffering in php can be nested, and CI seems to use it, opening a buffer for each view being loaded.
If we load a view from inside a view, the nesting gets deeper, and generally, when an error occures in the view we don't know how deep we are.

So that's what seems to solve the problem (the code of error handler):

```
function _error_handler($errno, $errstr) {

    $currentLevel=ob_get_level();
    for($i=0; $i<$currentLevel-1; $i++) {
        ob_end_clean();
    }

    print "errorrrr!";
    die();

}
```

so it detects how deep it is and cleans as many buffers as needed. After all, we end up with "errorrrr" message being the only thing on the page.