# I want to display an 404 error without redirecting

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess

I need to show a 404 error page in all pages that are not valid without redirecting them.
Currently when /wrong-page is entered it redirects to /404. But I want to display the 404 page's content within /wrong-page.

Also my website doesn't use PHP, so is there any way to do this with html and js, or even with htaccess?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Display a 404 Error without redirecting to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137625/php-display-a-404-error-without-redirecting-to-another-page)

Answer (score 1):

To control that with PHP, you will need to use the `.htaccess` file.

For instance, if you want to process some script, then this `.htaccess` file....

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Will redirect to `index.php` *without rewriting the URL*.  This means you can simply control the exception handling in index.php with...

```
$someNon404Condition = file_exists($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if ($someNon404Condition) {
    include($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);   // do the stuff
} else {
    print("404!  Why are you trying to access " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?");
}
```

This will give you greater control over the error that displays for the `404`, for instance, you can have the page display `Unable to process $_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME] for URL 123/456/,`, etc.

This lets you do tons of other things, too!  Forget a static 404.html page, with a dynamic one you can...

- Your condition can be as complicated as you can code: check authentication, check for permanent redirects, maybe you want to expire content automatically?  Etc., etc..
- Search your DB for `explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`, and then display a list of those matched results under the header "Maybe this is what you were looking for?"
- Respond to user-level events: Is it a 404 because the page was moved?  Then handle a redirect.  Is it a 404 because a moderator deleted it and it was the user's post?  Tell the user a moderator deleted their post.  Etc., etc..
- Make API calls, dynamic code, etc., etc., the possibilities are there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `.htaccess` file
Place this in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.html [L]
```

The `404.html` must be the error page which must display when there is a 404 error.

Comment: Yes I am currently using this. But it redirects to another page. I want the 404 to be displayed in the same page with the same url.

Comment: I have changed the answer. See if this works now :)